# How to simplify custom multi checkbox component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have strange (at least to me) problem with multiple checkboxes with v-model. When using multiple checkboxes that are `v-model`'ed to one property then normal array is produced which is done with code below:

```
.form-check
  input.form-check-input(type=“checkbox” name=“checkbox” v-model=“methodology” value=“issue tracking tool”)
  label.form-check-label issue tracking tool
```

However, when I try to move it to Single File Component I had to copy some magical tricks from Vue.js forum to make it work. I still suspect that there must be easier way to achieve it. I can’t imagine that it wasn’t solved with simple solutions since it’s quite a common pattern (checkbox in a component - nothing exotic, right?). Any help appreciated!

Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0x0u9v9/) - please have in mind that there is no errors. I just want to know if that really has to be that complicated.

Comment: Please include your code in the post itself (it's not too long and this ensures that a broken link doesn't affect the quality of this post in the future). But also, can you clarify your question? What isn't working as expected and can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verfiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the issue?

Comment: I will try to provide working sample. In the meantime: the provided gist is working, but it's still quite complicated and I don't think it should be as complicated. That's why I'm asking for help...or maybe refactoring to be exact.

Comment: I provided working example and edited question.

Comment: could you clarify what you are expecting to see?

Comment: I'm expecting to see the same, but with less boilerplate inside `my-input` component (as for now there is going on quite a lot as for simple task like this). I suspect that this code is overcomplicated and could be simplified - I just can't get the right information to do so. Comparing it to simple text inputs it's a lot of code.

Comment: It's confusing, because you have some code related to slugs and errors, I'm guessing that's not related to the problem. And defining 'value' **and** 'val' is perhaps what you mean by *some magical tricks*?

Comment: The `error` is actually simple because it get data straight from the prop. What I meant by saying _some magical tricks_ was e.g. computed property `checked` which has explicit `get`ter and `set`ter or `checkedProxy` data property which I don't know what it's function really is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, no. You may be able to do this *magic* differently, but it needs to be done.

Vue has to do magic behind the scenes for checkbox because unlike all the other inputs, which have a single item that gets updated, the checkbox has to manage whether the a value is in an array. This means that the listeners and values have to be patched between the wrapper and input.

Comment: you can look at how some libraries have implemented it. Here's an example of how vue bootrstrap did it: https://github.com/znck/bootstrap-for-vue/blob/master/src/mixins/checkbox.js

Comment: That's why I asked because if instead of creating custom component I would use multiple checkboxes directly `v-model`ing same data prop it's as easy as it would be text one. That's why I asked - because standard implementation is sooooooo easy and nice.